# How exactly do minor page faults get identified/resolved?

Tags: linux-kernel, shared-memory

I feel very clear on what happens with a segmentation fault and a major page fault, but I'm a bit more curious on the subtleties of minor page faults, and maybe an example would be with dynamically linked libraries. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault#Minor) says, for instance:

> If the page is loaded in memory at the time the fault is generated, but is not marked in the memory management unit as being loaded in memory, then it is called a minor or soft page fault. The page fault handler in the operating system merely needs to make the entry for that page in the memory management unit point to the page in memory and indicate that the page is loaded in memory; it does not need to read the page into memory. This could happen if the memory is shared by different programs and the page is already brought into memory for other programs.

The line, "The page fault handler in the operating system merely needs to make the entry for that page in the memory management unit point to the page in memory" confuses me. Each process has its own  page table. So if  I try to map in, say, `libc`,  what's the process that the kernel goes through to figure out that it's already  been mapped? How does it know that another process is using it or that there's already a frame associated with it? Does this happen with the page cache? I was reading a bit about it [here](https://manybutfinite.com/post/page-cache-the-affair-between-memory-and-files/), but I think some clarification would be nice on the steps that occur in the kernel to identify and resolve a minor page fault would be helpful.

Edit: It [looks](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~porter/courses/cse506/s16/slides/page-cache-handout.pdf) like a radix tree is used to keep track? Although I'm not quite sure I'm understanding this correctly.

Comment: A minor fault means the page is in memory but not allocated to the requesting process or not marked as present in the memory management unit. A major fault means the page in no longer in memory.

Comment: @Wyck that I understand, it's the part about how the kernel "realizes" that it's already in memory that I don't quite get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, the kernel has no idea if the page is in memory or not. Presumably, the process does have a handle open to the file however, so the kernel performs an operation through the kernel-side file descriptor entry. This involves calling into the filesystem which, of course, knows what pages of the file are resident in memory since it's the code that would load the page were one needed.

Comment: What if it's just a shared anonymous mapping? Surely that won't go through the filesystem to grab the page? I thought maybe it had to do with a reverse mapping being stored or the page cache.

Comment: If it's a shared anonymous mapping, it's already mapped. It just triggers a page fault so the OS can do the copy on write or other tracking. But in that case, the information is stored in the virtual memory map for the process -- the same as the information you get from /proc/<pid>/maps